# Toast inside onClick method in Fragment

Tags: android, onclick, android-fragments, toast

I have a following Fragment:

```
public class FragmentSocial extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener, OnClickListener 
{

private Fragment mFragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_social);
}

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // relevant code...
}

public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // relevant code...
}

public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.imgBtnFB:
        Toast.makeText(this, "FB pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case R.id.imgBtnTwitter:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Twitter pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }

}
```

I have a few image buttons in my `fragment_social` layout. For now I just want to make a Toast message to see what button was pressed. However, if I use `this` as context, I'm getting this error message:
*The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentSocial, String, int)*
I tried to change `this` to `FragmentSocial.this`, to `FragmentSocial.this.getActivity()`, tried to create `private Context mContext` and to instantiate it to `mContext = (I tried various options here)` inside the onCreate method - but nothing worked. I either didn't have an error message, but also didn't see the Toast, or got other errors.

So how can I create a Toast here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use:

```
getActivity().getBaseContext();
```

Comment: Do you mean like that: `Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "FB pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`? Tried it, still didn't work... Also tried `Toast.makeText(FragmentSocial.this.getActivity().getBaseContext(), "FB pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` - didn't work, didn't see the Toast.

Comment: right. that should work. Put Log.d("test", "test") inside the onClick() and see if you have a message in Logcat. You would know then whether your onClick() method is called or not.

Comment: Nop, I didn't see the Log message. Guess I'm doing something wrong here... I also tried to do something like that in the onCreate method: `findViewById(R.id.imgBtnFB).setOnClickListener(this);` but I don't even have the `findViewById` method available for some reason.

Comment: Try to inflate your layout from onCreateView():

Comment: Remove everything from onCreate (keep super only) and create onCreateView() like this: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_social, container, false);
        return view;
    }

Comment: Yes, just did, wanted to write here that the problem is solved :) After that I registered the buttons for onClickListener like that: `view.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnFB).setOnClickListener(this);` and everything finally worked like it should! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I used getApplication() instead of getActivity() in Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "FB pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();, so I used Toast.makeText(getApplication().getBaseContext(), "FB pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); and it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

If you are using fragment then use this code

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You have insufficient points", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
```

Comment: This is the shortest and simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Either of the following lines work.

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer by Marcin S., you could also setup the constructor inside the Fragment and pass in a context variable. You can then use this context anytime you wish to reference the activity. This method is also slightly quicker then `getActivity().getBaseContext()`

Add this to your FragmentSocial class:

```
Context context;
public FragmentSocial(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

When you ever say `FragmentSocial fragmentSocial = new FragmentSocial();` in your main activity class, add the paramter `this` into the `()` to make it look like `FragmentSocial fragmentSocial = new FragmentSocial(this);`

Comment: @Igal Check my revised answer.

Comment: I tried it and got this error message: *Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead* I also had to create an empty constructor, as I had more errors (I have this code in my onTabSelected method - `mFragment = new FragmentSocial();`)

Answer (score 0):

This is way i do in fragment

//edit

```
 YourActivity activity;


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
   this.activity = (YourActivity) activity;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this.activity, "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: The drawback of this approach is that you are mapping fragment to an activity. So it is not reusable with other activities.