# Showing a Toast in Text To Speech if not Supported

Tags: android, android-fragments, text-to-speech, android-context, android-toast

When adding Toast to TTS button in Fragement , i get this error **"Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext()"** even i tried `getActivty()`. and `getContext()`. , then more errors showed up,this is the toast :

**Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();**

Here is the fragement code :

```
  TextToSpeech toSpeech;
    int result;
    EditText editText;
    String text;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        editText = v.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        toSpeech = new TextToSpeech(HomeFragment.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    Locale locale = new Locale("tr-TR");
                    int result = toSpeech.setLanguage(locale);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                }
            }
        });


        return v;
    }

    public void TTS(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.bplay:
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                } else {
                    text = editText.getText().toString();
                    toSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    toSpeech.setSpeechRate((float) 0.8);
                    toSpeech.setPitch((float) 0.7);

                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (toSpeech != null) ;
        {
            assert toSpeech != null;
            toSpeech.stop();
            toSpeech.shutdown();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toast inside onClick method in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364315/toast-inside-onclick-method-in-fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> new TextToSpeech(HomeFragment.this

You should use [**`getActivity()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()).

> Return the FragmentActivity this fragment is currently associated
>   with.

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
new TextToSpeech(getActivity()
```

**Finally**

```
toSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                Locale locale = new Locale("tr-TR");
                int result = toSpeech.setLanguage(locale);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> First of all,

In your code you have given **HomeFragment.this** which is not proper in fragment.

```
toSpeech = new TextToSpeech(**HomeFragment.this**, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    Locale locale = new Locale("tr-TR");
                    int result = toSpeech.setLanguage(locale);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                }
            }
        });
```

You need to change **HomeFragment.this with getActivity()** and also change **getApplicationContext() with getActivity()** in your code like below : -

```
toSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                        Locale locale = new Locale("tr-TR");
                        int result = toSpeech.setLanguage(locale);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    }
                }
            });
```

> Second Option

If in case still Toast is not working properly using getActivity() then you can also try

```
getActivity().getBaseContext();
```

like below:-

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: The first one is working too ,i just changed the "getActivity"  thanks.

Comment: @Cristina99 I have also given true answer with more information and understanding. and you have already accepted my answer first right? then Why?